# Sqlite3 : Wrong table became deleted during attach database query from python

Tags: python, sqlite

I`m using SQLite version 3.3.6  from python 2.7.2.

While executing this query with `executescript()` from python script:

```
attach database 'Capacity.db' as WeekAgo;
drop table if exists maximums;
create table maximums (Element TEXT UNIQUE, Score NUMBER , Report TEXT);
insert into maximums (Element, Score, Report) select * from WeekAgo.maximums;
```

I always ending up with deletion of WeekAgo.maximums table in attached database and script crashing that no WeekAgo.maximums exists anymore. What am I doing wrong? Without `DROP IF EXISTS`, everything works fine.

Comment: I`m amused why  during DROP it drops  WeekAgo.maximums instead of maximums ??? It can at least say that maximums not found ,  to  force me use DB name as prefix, to strictly identify tables. Actually exactly what you suggested below.  I  expect some error to point me that i did not identified table properly.

Comment: "The optional IF EXISTS clause suppresses the error that would normally result if the table does not exist." https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `main` keyword:

```
attach database 'Capacity.db' as WeekAgo;
drop table if exists main.maximums;
create table main.maximums (Element TEXT UNIQUE, Score NUMBER , Report TEXT);
insert into main.maximums (Element, Score, Report) select * from WeekAgo.maximums;
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

> If two or more tables in different databases have the same name and the database-name prefix is not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the database that was least recently attached.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.  It is really unexpected behaviour. Logically , without DB prefix, it should use DB that was opened first , like main workplace.

Comment: Logicially it should behave as documented :)

Comment: I've sent a link of this post to the relevant reporting system - will post an update if it gets a ticket number or something.

Comment: Not necessarily an error; just not the behaviour one is led to expect.